# GTK Headerbar styling so that all buttons are aligned to the left

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk

Is it possible to adjust GTK theme or app behaviour so that all buttons in the Header bar in all applications are aligned to the left side? 
What is the best way to do it (CSS possibly, source modificatons)? 
If it's not possible, then why?

If it matters: Ubuntu version is 19.04, libgtk-3-0: 3.24.8-1ubuntu1

See the attached screenshot for a visual explanation.

[image: Screenshot showing the desired position of the icons]